# Fixing Flash's aggressive caching

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, caching

I have a flash application that loads a big chunk of data that changes **occasionally**, so I set up my server to send `Last-Modified` headers and reply with a `304 Not Modified` when the client's version is not outdated.

It works fine in every browser, but Flash completely ignores that and caches the resource aggressively. It doesn't even send a request to the server, it just retrieves the cached file from disk when you try to `URLLoader.load` a previously visited URL.

The workarounds I find on google aren't helpful for me - either you cache forever or redownload the resource every time (changing the URL parameters). I need a mixture of these - redownload when the resource is updated, use cache otherwise.

Comment: How about storing a local SharedObject on the client's machine to keep track of their latest download. If the Shared Object doesn't exist, it's the user's 1st visit. If it's there check the date stored in the Shared Object against the Last-Modified date on the server. If the client has an old download, update, otherwise don't. If the file the client needs to download has the same name/gets cached automatically, use the old url trick with the random number at the end (e.g. 'FileForDownload.zip?r='+new Date().milliseconds or Math.random() )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a version number as URL parameter... This way it won't be re-downloaded each time Flash Player loads, only when you actually change the version number

Comment: Yep, I realised that seconds after posting the question :)

Comment: +1: Using the current timestamp also works very well for making the URL unique, thus preventing caching.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work but it's worth trying.

You could try appending a cache breaker code to the file request. Normally, you would do this by attaching a random string of characters to the end of the file name e.g. `new URLRequest("bigFile.foo?uncache=273095285209750")`. For you, instead of using a random string you could use a date object to generate the string. For example...

```
var now:Date = new Date();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("bigFile.foo?uncache=" + new Date(now.year, now.month, now.date));
```

That would hopefully force the content to recache once per day (or hour or however often you want). If you need even more granular control, you could write a short server side script to see whether the file has been modified and check that before requesting the huge download.

I hope this helps!