# Flash app not updating well on server

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, refresh

I'm trying to learn as3 in flash development but I'm having a hard time following because of the refresh that's not working well in flash.

I have external as3 classes but when I edit something like content_txt.text = 'something else' it doesn't even change on the flash app on the server.

Even when I change the background color of my flash app, republish it and put in on the server to replace the old one. Still the old one is displayed.

How can I get around this? cause it's very frustrating to learn and develop stuff that won't cooperate. I'm trying to have facebook integration if anyone's asking.

Answer (score 2):

Do you refresh your browser with Ctrl+F5 to clear the cache? Some browsers may not notice the new `.swf` file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check the answer to this question:
[Fixing Flash's aggressive caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432222/fixing-flashs-aggressive-caching/4432377#4432377)

Practically you can force Flash Player to reload the movie by appending parameters to the swf url. Several methods are offered in the answers , pick the one that suits you best!

Comment: How is this relevant? Here we have the browser caching the swf, not the swf caching an external URL like happened there.